# Valid jQuery selector syntax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expression

Is this valid syntax?

```
$('.' + type).append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
```

This is the full section

```
$('.submit-items').click(function() {
   var type = $('.food-list .active li').text();
   var value = foodLoads[type];
   $('.' + type).append('<p>' + value + '</p>');
})
```

Everytime I click the button I get this error

"jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .

```
                mango"
```

mango is one of the possible results of text in ('.food-list .active li').text()

This is the object:

```
  var foodLoads = {
    orange: 6.7,
    apple: 5.6,
    banana: 12.7,
    grapes: 16.3,
    peach: 2.7,
    pear: 6.5,
    mango: 16.1,
    blueberries: 9.3,
    grapefruit: 1.7,
    strawberries: 3.5,
    tangerine: 3.1,
    watermelon: 8,
    duck: 0,
    beef: 0,
    chicken: 0,
    ham: 0,
    turkey: 0,
    elk: 0,
    pork: 0,
    fish: 0,
    eggs: 0,
    lamb: 0,
    applejuice: 11.8,
    cranberryjuice: 23.3,
    orangejuice: 14.4,
    carrotjuice: 8.6,
    lemonade: 24.3,
    hotchocolatemix: 10.2,
    tomatojuice: 3.5,
    chocolatemilk: 13.3,
    almondmilk: 0.02,
    soymilk: 4,
    wholewheatbread: 6.1,
    whitebread: 10.7,
    bagel: 30,
    waffle: 13.8,
    pancake: 5.3,
    croissant: 12.2,
    muffin: 28.8,
    englishmuffin: 21.3,
    doughnut: 15.2,
    oatmeal: 12.6,
    quinoa: 20.4,
    wholegrainbread: 7.1 
  }
```

Comment: yes it's valid syntaxe, just make a fiddle or a demo would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems legit, but the error message

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .
```

is caused by your selector not returning anything, or `text()` being empty. Meaning something in here is wrong:

`$('.food-list .active li')`

If this selector doesn't match anything, or `text()` returns an empty string, that slighty cryptic error message appears. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjolie/f386gzzh/

The actual bug is then caused by

`$('.' + type).append('<p>' + value + '</p>')` being evaluated as

`$('.').append('<p>' + value + '</p>')`, which obviously fails.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. The only reason I can see why this would be a problem is due to the fact that what the first selector points to is created dynamically as the user checks a checkbox (prior to pressing submit button). Although, by the time the user presses the button, the selected item has already been created, so In don't see why it shouldn't work at that point. I'll go thought it again and upload a fiddle if it still doesn't work.